# there is an isomorphism of $GL(V)$ modules $V^* \simeq \Lambda^{n}V^* \otimes \Lambda^{n-1}V $

Tags: linear-algebra, modules, tensors

how to prove that there is an isomorphism of $GL(V)$ modules $V^* \simeq \Lambda^{n}V^* \otimes \Lambda^{n-1}V$, where $V$ is $n$ dimensional vector space?

I was trying to prove it in the following way:

choose a basis of $V=\langle v_1,...v_n \rangle$, then for an element $\alpha \in V^*$ choose a $V \supset C=coim(\alpha)$, coimage of $\alpha$ in $V$. If the dimension of $C$ is $n-1$ then take any $n-1$ elements spanning $C$, namely $c_1,c_2,...c_{n-1}$ and define a tensor in $\Lambda^{n}V^* \otimes \Lambda^{n-1}V$ by $ v_1 \wedge...\wedge v_n \otimes c_1 \wedge...\wedge c_{n-1}$. If the dimension of $C$ is $n$ then define the image as a zero tensor.

However this is not $GL(V)$ module homomorphism (only $SL(V)$) because I multiply by a determinant.
How should I prove it correctly? (putting $det(v_1,...,v_n)^{-1}$ in front of $v_1 \wedge...\wedge v_n \otimes c_1 \wedge...\wedge c_{n-1}$ can be not well defined for linearly dependent $v_1,...,v_n$)

Comment: Do you mean $\nu = n$?

Comment: yes, thank both of you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure this is what you're looking for, but I didn't check all the details. Define $$(\phi_1\wedge\cdots\wedge \phi_{n-1})\otimes (v_1\wedge\cdots\wedge v_n)=\sum_{\sigma\in S_{n}}\sum_{\tau\in S_{n-1}} (-1)^{|\sigma|+|\tau|}[\phi_{\sigma(1)}(v_{\tau(1)})\cdots \phi_{\sigma(n-1)}(v_{\tau_{n-1}})]v_{\tau(n)}.$$
Where the sum is over permutations and $|\sigma|$ is the parity of the permutation. This is a map  $\Lambda^n V^*\otimes \Lambda^{n-1}V\to V.$ Is it onto? Is it a GL(V)-map? Is it injective? (Hint: count dimensions.)

Comment: I will think about it, but now I see a typo: there should be $(v_{\tau(1)})$